# Electrical characteristics of GPIO

Tags: gpio, electronics

Is there a spec sheet anywhere which lists the electrical specifications for the varios GPIO pins on the RPi revision B? For example, if they are open collector etc, output voltage, max input voltage, max sink/source current, and so on?

I assume it's different between the different types, e.g. PWM, I2C etc, and obviously if they're programmed as inputs or outputs.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, Broadcom does not seem to provide the full (electical) spec on their web site, unlike other SoC manufactures. I've been looking for those specs, too.

Comment: <rant> It is ridiculous but it seems that the data for the electrical properties of the SoC is not readily available!  As an electrical and electronic engineer I'd expect to have access to the voltage and current levels (minimum/typical/maximum OR absolute limit depending on the nature of the characteristic) and timing data - **it is essential to properly design interface circuitry and this is a device that the Foundation wants user to be able to wire into projects!** </rant>

Comment: also relevant: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/60218/19949

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a bit of information about the GPIOs on the [lowlevel peripherals page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_hardware_hacking) (and linked pages) on the [Embedded Linux wiki](http://elinux.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are no extra ICs for the GPIO ports, so have you taken a look at the [Broadcom Spec](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)?