# RPi 3 3.3v GPIO normal current

Tags: gpio

so I've read around forums that the max current from a RPi 3.3v GPIO pin is 50 mA, but since it is the max I don't know if I should take a resistor for 50 mA or for a lower current.

Comment: What you have read is **WRONG** (or at best a misinterpretation of the limitations of the original Pi). See [Electrical Specifications of GPIO](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60218/what-are-the-electrical-specifications-of-gpio-pins/60219#60219)

Answer (score 2):

You have been misinformed.

The 50 mA is for the GPIO as a whole. (This applies to the original Pi A & B; the B+ and later (with 40 pin header), including the Pi Zero, have no such limit.)

It is generally suggested that you don't try to draw more than 16 mA from a single GPIO (although the 16 mA figure is actually how much can be drawn before the GPIO can't reliably signal a logical high).

You need to expand your question to explain what you want to do if you want a useful answer.

Comment: OK, but for example, if you write a simple program to turn on an led, the GPIO pin sends all of the 16mA?

Comment: The GPIO will send as much as it can, which can be a lot more than 16 mA (perhaps even more than 50 mA).  Normally the thing you connect will have a resistance to limit the current.  In the case of a LED it has no resistance so it needs a resistor in series to prevent the LED burning out.