# Output/Input Voltage/Curent of RaspberryiPi 3 B

Tags: gpio, pi-3

**I looked everywhere but i didn't found a good answer.**

I'm looking for the specifications of my **RaspberryiPi 3 B** because i need to connect it with many sensors like LDR sensor or Distance sensor (Inputs) and with a L293D to controll motors (Outputs).

*But i would know how much Voltage/Curent i can use in my Output/Input pins?*

And there is 5V(2 pins) and 3.3V(2 pins) output pins in my RaspberryPi, how much curent does they deliver?

**PS: I have a supply of 5V 2A.**

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Sorry but I am not going with "did not find a good answer" here, Milliways linked to two which address exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 2):

There are many posts on these subjects, including on this site, many providing authoritative answers. Unfortunately there is no definitive documentation on some aspects. I have collated the following from many sources, and augmented with testing.

[Electrical Specifications of GPIO](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60218/what-are-the-electrical-specifications-of-gpio-pins/60219#60219)

[Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)