# GPIO Voltage tolerance for input

Tags: gpio, input-device, voltage

I have not been able to find the input tolerance on I/O pins, especially on the Input pins. If I apply a voltage 3.6v (3.3v +0.3) on an input will it be dangerous or is it ok ?

Does somebody have a technical datasheet?

Comment: The BCM2835 is the GPIO interface chip, and the datasheet is missing some "electrical" data as max input voltage. This url points to a NON official site http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no formal published data, but the following summarises what I have been able to discover. [Electrical Specifications of GPIO](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60218/what-are-the-electrical-specifications-of-gpio-pins/60219#60219)

I would NOT apply 3.6V to a GPIO pin, but if the voltage does not exceed Vcc + diode voltage (~0.7V) damage is unlikely. I would use a serial resistor in any event.

If you know the voltage may be excessive use a resistive divider. Any voltage >2.0V will be HIGH (actually the threshold is more like 1.3V)